# Is it respectful to praise/refer gods by the name 'Urdhwareta"?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, scripture, vishnu-sahasranama

Urdhwareta is one of the 1000 names given to Lord Shriman Narayana in Vishnu Sahastranaam, which literally means ithyphallic. Same name is given to the Last 24th Avatar of Lord Rudra named [Lakulish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakulish). Now since Lord Rudra is worshipped as Linga, it may be okay for him to be Urdhwareta but as Shriman Narayana is full of Sattva and other auspicious qualities, how is it suitable for him to be Urdhwareta as it is indication for Lust inside a human being.

Even if Shriman Narayana or Lord Rudra both are urdhwareta how is it respectful and ethical to write that name in scriptures and worship them by that name.

Comment: Do you know what the number of that name is in the Vishnu Sahasranamam?  I can look up how the name is interpreted in the commentaries of Adi Shankaracharya and Parashara Bhattar.

Comment: Yogi, Linga doesn't mean Phallus always. Linga is symbol. When a baby is born, how do you identify him/her? Linga represents **mark** to identify. We classify things as पुलिंग (Pulinga), स्त्री-लिंग (stree linga) and नपुंसक लिंग (Napusaka Linga) which are equivalents of Masculine, feminine and neuter. Also, does Shiva Lingam look like Phallus? This was propagated by anti Hindus that we worship a phallus god and people still stick to it. If you see carefully, Linga is away from base not towards it in a Shiva Lingam.

Comment: It is leela of God to be called by that name. If you believe Sriman Narayana as everything, then why do you limit him to only Sattva? Where did you see that meaning? i checked ऊर्ध्वरेत  in [this dictionary](http://andhrabharati.com/dictionary/sanskrit/index.php) and it says **who keeps semen above, living in chastity**. Can you add Devanagari  spelling for that word?

Comment: @TheDestroyer this is the devnagri spelling ऊर्ध्वरेता

Comment: ऊर्ध्वरेत has meaning but not ऊर्ध्वरेता. Check in Sanskrit dictionaries and word is not offensive. Word represents a chaste man, which applies for both Vishnu and Shiva.

Comment: @TheDestroyer ऊर्ध्वरेत is an adjective but  ऊर्ध्वरेता is noun which defines a person rather than the characterstic. So dictonary might be correct but the wikipedia page shows image description of lakulisha and in every image he is shown naked and ithyphallic.

Comment: Wikipedia is wrong, Yogi. The word means someone who has , through yoga, achieved the state of turning their energy upwards towards the sahasrara when its natural course is to move downwards.  It means someone in full control of their fully risen Kundalini. It means someone who is a true brahmachari. Lord Narayana is a natural yogi.

Comment: @moonstar2001 I don't believe in chakra and things related to it. It is a medieval concept. Thankyou for pointing that out but I think Urdhwareta is the one who moves up in the context of Vaikuntha / Parmapada which is upwards. Yeah Shriman Narayana is yoga itself he is bramhan.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is respectful. Name Urdhwareta is used to describe ParaBrahman itself by the Vedas. In the **Yajurveda Taittariya Aranyaka 10.23.1** (and also in [Mahanarayana Upanishad](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/mahanarayana.html?lang=sa) 10.23) which is in the middle of Rudra Suktas it is stated:

> ऋतं सत्यं परं ब्रह्म पुरुषं कृष्णपिङ्गलम् ।
>   **ऊर्ध्वरेतं** विरूपाक्षं विश्वरूपाय वै नमो नमः ॥ १॥
>  
>   Absolute reality and the Supreme Brahman. He is the Purush who is dark blue and reddish brown (KrishnaPingala). **He is Urdhwareta.** He possesses uncommon eyes (Virupakshya). His form is the whole world. Salutation and Salutation to him.

As, the **Urdhwareta** name is given itself by the Eternal Vedas while describing Para Brahman, so there is no question of disrespect at all.